# jQuery preventDefault and return false not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement an image preview.  It works fine until i came to a problem where i need to prevent the `input file` to not change.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0aebg44o/1/)

When trying to change to image its fine.  After changing to image try to change the input file into a `txt` file.  its alerting the correct error, but the input file is also changed.

```
$('body').on('change','.input-preview',function(e){
    var ito = $(this);
    var img = ito[0].files;
    var errs = [];
    for(x=0;x<img.length;x++){
        if(img[x].type!=='image/jpeg' && img[x].type!=='image/gif' && img[x].type!=='image/png'){
            errs.push('Not image.');
            break;
        }
        if(img[x].size>(1024000 * 5)){ 
            errs.push('File is too big.');
            break;
        }
    }
    if(errs.length){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(errs[0]);
        return false;
    }else{
      previewIt(this, $('.preview-profile'));
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `change` event is not cancelable. See the document on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change).

Comment: thank you for your answer. is there a way to achieve what i want?

Answer (score 0):

Since `change` is not a `cancelable` event, you can manually remove an item when you want to "cancel" it.

The following example will not accept files of size > 1024 bytes.

```js
$("#fileInput").change(function() {
  if (this.files[0].size > 1024) {
    $("#result").text("File size exceeds 1024 bytes");
    this.value = "";
  } else {
    $("#result").text("OK");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="fileInput"/>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: but this will erase the past file data